# Load Balancing WFE with SSRS?

Tags: 2007

Can I load balance my SharePoint Web Front Ends, when one runs SSRS on it? If yes, what would be the recommended specifications for that particular node? And would there be any implications to this approach?

Thank You,
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can although you won't have high availability of SSRS. Use Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM) to allocate what ever addidtional CPU/RAM you have given this WFE and prevent all the SharePoint 2010 services/web apps from using the extra compaired with the other WFE. This is a lot of work. Best to have another SharePoint Server dedicated to SSRS (cheap unless this is Internet facing but then SSRS is not supported in anonymous mode anyway).

The URL for SSRS web service must use a dedicated URL (domain name), not the NLB address.

Comment: yup, I think due to the fact SSRS web service requires a dedicated URL I've decided to have SSRS as a stand-alone (WFE installed but disbled) and the build another WFE node for load balancing. It does cost more, but leaves a lot of flexibility and scalability options open. Thank you for the feedback, cheers.